# Add D-Pad Support To App

Tags: applications, apk, accessibility, input-methods, text-input

Nowadays, flip phones run android. You are able to install any app, as long as it supports the framework. But, the one problem is that there is no touchscreen on flip phones. Is there a way to add "D-Pad" functionality to a common android app, much like the way you use the remote to navigate on AndroidTV?

Comment: [Gamepads are mapped to keys on Android](https://developer.android.com/training/game-controllers/controller-input) but as Android devices usually don't have a keyboard most developers don't process key events, therefore the gamepads don't work. Making an app work with a gamepad would require to modify it's code which is technically possible for skilled developers (unless the app is somewhow protected and obfuscated) but also a legal problem.

Comment: @Robert I know that, I'm looking for some help in the adding of functionality/editing of the source code- and the app I am editing belongs to me.

Comment: I am sorry but this site is for end users not app developers. Check the link in my first comment it describes how to implement key handling in Android apps.

Comment: @Robert ok thank you, this is also the way I would need to go with other apps too?